# Конь прядёт или прядает ушами?

Tags: этимология, семантика, глаголы

Почему конь *прядёт* ушами? Есть здесь семантическая корреляция с глаголом *прясть* в привычном его понимании?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Здесь ошибка в употреблении слова "прядёт" в значении *шевелит*; конь ушами *пряд**ае**т.*

Сравним две словарные статьи,

глагол *прясть*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и глагол *прядать*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

—  не совпадает ни одна словоформа, так что это даже не омонимы или омографы.

Изменения глагола *прядать* можно посмотреть в таблице:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прядает/прядёт - паронимы.

Comment: Спасибо, Галина!